# What tense should I use for a completed action before another action expressed in present perfect?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

I know I can use Past Perfect talks about a completed action before another action, for example:

```
I had eaten before she arrived at 10:00am.
```

But I am not sure what tense I should used for a completed action before another action expressed in present perfect.

```
I [eat ? tense] before she has arrived.
```

Any suggestion on what tense I should use to express this kind of chronology?

Comment: You can at best use, "I have eaten before she has arrived."

Comment: Do you have a scenario in mind where you would need to use that tense? I suppose someone might say "I have eaten before she has arrived because I'm sure she will have had a meal on the journey", but it doesn't sound at all natural.

Comment: @KateBunting My scenario is like: "Regarding the proposal, John has already provided a supportive view to the previous proposal from financial perspective and Peter has provided a supportive view to the revised proposal from technical perspective." So the support of John is provided prior the support of Peter.

Comment: That's perfectly OK - you are referring to two things that have already happened. "Before she has arrived" is different, because it implies that she hasn't arrived yet..